# Web cam video doesn't start in browser. Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, face-api

Hello I have a application in rails5 with face-api.js library for face recognition. But in my browser the video of webcam doesnt work and in my console doesnt show anywere errors. I'm not understand whats is happennig. [image: here a screenshot of the browser]

This is my code of the view:

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'face_recognition.js'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "face-api.js/dist/face-api.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "face-api.js/dist/face-api.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'face_api'%>

     
      <style>
        canvas{
          position: relative;
            top: -420px;
            left: 350px;
        }
      </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      
        <video  id="camfr" autoplay="autoplay" width="400" height="400" muted></video>
    
    </body>
```

This is my app/assets/javascripts/face_recognition.js

```
//require face_recognition
```

And in my lib/assets/javascripts i have the face_recogniton.js file where load the camera, canvas and the models of face-api.js.

```
const camfr = document.getElementById('camfr')
    
const startVideo = () => {

    var constraints = { audio: false, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(mediaStream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject = mediaStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                video.play();
            };
        })
 
}

Promise.all([
   faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('vendorface-api.js/models/tiny_face_detector/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),
   faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_landmark_68/face_landmark_68_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"), //desenha os traços do rosto
   faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_recognition/face_recognition_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//faz o conhecimento do rosto
   faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_expression/face_expression_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//detecta expressoes
   faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/age_gender_model/age_gender_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//idade e genero
   faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/ssd_mobilenetv1/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-weights_manifest.json') %>") // usada para detectar rosto
]).then(startVideo)

camfr.addEventListener('play', async () => {
const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(camfr)
const canvasSize = {
    width: camfr.width,
    height: camfr.height
}
faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, canvasSize)
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi
    .detectAllFaces(
        camfr,
        new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()
        )
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceExpressions()
        .withAgeAndGender()
        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, canvasSize)
        canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
        faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
        faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)

        resizedDetections.forEach(detection => {
            const {age, gender, genderProbability} = detection
            new faceapi.draw.DrawTextField([
                        `${parseInt(age, 10)} years`,
                        `${gender} (${ parseInt(genderProbability * 100, 10)})`
                    ], detection.detection.box.topRight).draw(canvas)
})

}, 100)
})
```

Comment: have you tried it on https? webrtc doesn't work on chrome if its not served in a secured connection.